# Nextjs i18next can I serve or point to a different file when sub-path locale changes in URL?

Tags: next.js, routes, localization, internationalization, next-i18next

In NextJS's routing system, if I navigate to `//mysite.com/about/` it serves my project file `pages/about.js`

But when using **i18n** to add `mysite.com/fr/`, it still serves `pages/about.js`, not `pages/fr/about.js`. This is fine in most cases because you want to serve the same file and just change the text by detecting the locale **/fr/** with useRouter.

But in my case I want to serve a completely different file based on the sub-path **/fr/** in the pathname.

In `_app.js` I have props of `Component`, `pageProps` and `router`, but it's too late to conditionally serve a different file at this point because Component has already been determined by NextJS. Even though the prop `router.inFlightMode` has detected the language change.

I'm hoping there is simply a routing config to change somewhere that will include the sub-path in the pathname used to point to a file.

Comment: it may be fallbackLng is something that could help: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#fallback-locales

Comment: You could look into using [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewrites-with-i18n-support) to map the `/fr` paths to different destinations.